# Get-Filehash SHA256 encryption in powershell drops last 4 digits when run from a batch file

Tags: powershell, encryption, cmd, sha256

When I run the Get-Filehash from powershell it works however:

When I run it from a batch file, it drops last 4 digits.

```
powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy -Command "Get-FileHash filename.edi -Algorithm SHA256 | Out-File c:\app\testfileout.txt"
```

> ```
> Algorithm       Hash                                                           
> ---------       ----                                                           
> SHA256          3EFEC59BFB0573061C5CD2F72A684663B60CA3D0D91C67CBDBBE366A59FE...
> ```

How do I get the output file to ONLY be:

> ```
> 3EFEC59BFB0573061C5CD2F72A684663B60CA3D0D91C67CBDBBE366A59FE4A8F
> ```

Which gives me the full hash inside Powershell when I run this:

```
Get-FileHash filename.edi -Algorithm SHA256 | Out-File c:\app\testfileout.txt
```

I need just the hash without the headers as well as the final 4 digits.

Does anyone have a script that already does this?

Comment: cmd.exe, despite appearances, is not DOS.

Answer (score 2):

It returns an object so all you need to do is use Select-Object with ExpandProperty:

```
powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy -Command "Get-FileHash filename.edi -Algorithm SHA256 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Hash | Out-File c:\app\testfileout.txt"
```

or reference the object property by dot notation:

```
powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy -Command "(Get-FileHash filename.edi -Algorithm SHA256).Hash | Out-File c:\app\testfileout.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

With pure [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd), you can do it like this:

```cmd
cmd /V /C for /F "tokens=*" %H in ('certutil -hashfile "filename.edi" SHA256 ^^^| find /V ":"') do @(set "HASH=%H" ^& echo !HASH: =!) > "C:\app\testfileout.txt"
```

In a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), it may look like this:

```cmd
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=*" %%H in ('
    certutil -hashfile "filename.edi" SHA256 ^| find /V ":"
') do @(
    set "HASH=%%H" & echo !HASH: =!
) > "C:\app\testfileout.txt"
endlocal
```